# Standalone HTML Application

Tags: hta

Is there an application that can create a **standalone HTA**, which means no need `'mshta.exe'` to run and not leaving any temporary files? i've try `'htaedit'` but it need `'mshta.exe'` and leave temporary files.

Comment: `HTA` is a type of file used by mshta.exe like `DOC` is type of file used by Word. You just can't run `HTA`s without mshta.exe.

Comment: Okay, but is there any `hta2exe` application which not leaving any temporary files?

Comment: If you mean those files in `.../Temporary Internet Files/Content...`, I doubt you could get rid of them. Actually mshta.exe provides only the window object and "security model" for HTA, rendering and JavaScript are executed by Internet Explorer.

Comment: no, the temporay files is `the hta file + embedded files`, and it's easy to found, i just need compile hta to exe without creating any temporary files...?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. I've tested a compiler a while ago, and it just extracted all files to the folder I had chosen while compilation. However, just try to google some compilers, maybe you'll find better than I did.

Comment: uh oh, okay, and thank's for comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that hta can be run standalone. it is more of an interpreted language which is interpreted by mshta.exe. sort of like how java byte code is interpreted by the jvm

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You could create a self extraction drive using iexpress.exe which :

1. zips a copy of mshta.exe and your hta file
2. unzips them to a temporary folder at runtime
3. and runs a specified command. eg : `mshta <the hta filename>.hta`

iexpress is commonly used to created quick and dirty installers.
I came to know of this process while finding a way to convert `.bat` / `.cmd` files to `.exe`